# Reinstalled OS X, rEFInd doesn't boot anymore and goes straight to OS X

Tags: dual-boot, macosx, refind

I was having [an issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143432/my-macbook-can-connect-to-ethernet-over-ubuntu-but-not-os-x) where I could connect to Ethernet on my Macbook over Ubuntu but not OS X, and after trying a variety of different things decided to just reinstall OS X.

After doing that, the rEFInd screen doesn't show up and just goes straight to OS X. This is what's in my partition inspector:

`Current GPT partition table:
 #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)
 2         409640    389765095  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      389765096    391034639  Mac OS X Boot
 4      391034640    392304175  Mac OS X HFS+
 5      392304640    456867839  Basic Data
 6      456867840    490233855  Linux Swap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reinstalled OSX, it cleared out the old boot information, namely rEFInd. The one and only way to fix this is to reinstall rEFInd.

Comment: Just did that, and it worked!

Comment: Actually, using `bless` to reinstate rEFInd as the default boot program will work without re-installing. That said, there's little downside to re-installing it; doing it that way will result in some some unnecessary file-copying, but otherwise similar results.

Comment: @RodSmith You can also just go into BIOS and change the boot order...